# Angular factory and its functions calling each other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory, angularjs-factory

How can I refer to a function inside a factory? Here is the example, I want `function2` to use `function1` while returning a result (which fails as it is):

```
angular.module('myapp').
  factory('ExampleFactory', function ($http, $rootScope) {
  return {
    function1: function (a,b) {
      return a + b;
    },
    function2: function (a,b,c) {
      return this.function1(a,b) * c
    },    
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option using the "Revealing Module" design pattern:

```
angular.module('myapp').
  factory('ExampleFactory', function ($http, $rootScope) {
  function function1 (a,b) {
      return a + b;
  }
  function function2 (a,b,c) {
      return function1(a,b) * c;
  }
  return {
      function1: function1,
      function2: function2,    
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    angular.module('myapp').
      factory('ExampleFactory', function ($http, $rootScope) {
        // define what ever function you want , outside of the return property
        function plus(a,b){
          return a + b;
        }

      return {
        function2: function (a,b,c) {
          // Now u can use that function here :
          return plus(a,b) * c
        }
      }
    })
```